# Using SSML (interpret-as="characters") removes punctuation

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-assistant-sdk

If I use the `<say-as interpret-as="characters"></say-as>` tag in my voice response, google assistant suddenly pronounces the whole response differently. It sounds as if google assistant removes punctuation without any reason. The pauses, which are initiated by the ".", are suddenly gone.

To reproduce this behaviour, just launch the actions on google simulator, choose "English (United States)" as langauge and listen to this audio snippet:

`<speak>This is a test with number spelled as digit. The number is <say-as interpret-as="characters">12345</say-as>. Ask me "What to do with this number?" if you'd like to have more information.</speak>`

If you remove the `<say-as interpret-as="characters"></say-as>` tag, the pronounciation works again:

`<speak>This is a test with number spelled as digit. The number is 12345. Ask me "What to do with this number?" if you'd like to have more information.</speak>`

This now sounds like it should sound. You will get the same result if you leave out the `speak` tag at all.

In German, this issue is even more critical. Using `<say-as interpret-as="characters"></say-as>` in a German voice response leads to a response which honestly is barely understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of "text normalization" in Google Assistant's TTS process.

Because of that, SSML without using the `<s>` element won't always do what you expect for pauses if you are using embedded markup like `<say-as>`.

Here's an example using `<s>` to provide intended pauses in the TTS:

```
<speak>
  This is a test with number spelled as digit.
  <s>The number is <say-as interpret-as="characters">12345</say-as>.</s>
  Ask me "What to do with this number?" if you'd like to have more information.
</speak>
```

You can still feel free to input multiple sentences separated by periods into SSML without needing `<s>` to separate sentences and let Google Assistant handle the break generation as long as you are not using embedded markup like `<say-as>`.

More information about the `<s>` element can be found in the docs where it talks about `<p>,<s>` 
https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml

It will link to the [W3C spec on those elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/#edef_paragraph).